# How to start ubuntu-touch on Nexus 7 3G Tilapia (nakasig)?

Tags: ubuntu-touch, nexus-7, 3g

I am trying run Ubuntu Touch on my Nexus 7 3G Tilapia, but I only see the "Google" splash screen. I have read many forums and found that the `/data` partition is different on Tilapia and Grouper (`mmcblk0p10` and `mmcblk0p9`).

How I can modify the cmdline and attach `datapart=/dev/mmcblk0p10` on it?

OK I solve it

```
 1.erase all on nexus ( optionally. I do it but not sure in my memory :))

 2.$abootimg -x saucy-preinstalled-system-armel+grouper.img

 3. edit bootimg.cfg 

    cmdline = console=tty1 datapart=/dev/mmcblk0p10 

 4. $abootimg --create saucy-preinstalled-system-armel+grouper.img -f bootimg.cfg -k zImage -r initrd.img 

 5. do fastboot flash all by official manual

 6. go to recovery mode and format data, cache and SDcard partitions

 7. reboot into recovery mode

 8. $adb push /path/to/your/downloaded/saucy-preinstalled-touch-armel+grouper.zip /sdcard/autodeploy.zip

 9. reboot into recovery mode and wait when install is finish

 10. reboot into recovery mode second time

 11. $adb push /path/to/your/downloaded/saucy-preinstalled-touch-armhf.zip /sdcard/autodeploy.zip

 12. reboot into recovery mode and wait when install is finish. After install you got system.
```

Screen responds on power button (lighter/darker). After some time it darkens.

I try install vncserver, but it say:
vncserver: The HOME environment variable is not set.

Comment: Please for your answers use the field above for answers. The button that say "Answer my question".

Answer (score 2):

> Just in case anyone else is looking for info on this,
>       - I did it (mine Tilapia nakasig).
>       - using the 2014-06-18 build of utopic: it works, almost:
>       GSM is hopelessly unworkable
>       camera is dead
>       bluetooth seems dead
>       but wifi runs ok
>
> You could probably poke around and find drivers for the camera and
>   bluetooth I guess
>       but GSM will be and remain hopelessly dead in the water,
>       unless you fix the ofonod (and probably a whole host of other things)

This is a perverse hack of
 https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Touch/Install#Manual_Download_.26_Installation

```
start here: (you need the bzr package to do this)
Get the bzr branch of project-rootstock-ng and,
(  much later ! )    run the rootstock-touch-install script.
```

cd to somewhere convenient in your home directory maybe

```
bzr branch lp:project-rootstock-ng
cd project-rootstock-ng
```

get these (put them somewhere convenient, like in the project-rootstock-ng folder ):

```
( http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-touch/daily-preinstalled/current/ )

> utopic-preinstalled-boot-armhf+grouper.img 
> utopic-preinstalled-recovery-armel+grouper.img
> utopic-preinstalled-system-armel+grouper.img 
> utopic-preinstalled-touch-armhf.tar.gz
```

run on your host (I was using Makulu and also LMDE for this)

```
abootimg -u utopic-preinstalled-boot-armhf+grouper.img -c "cmdline=console=tty1 datapart=/dev/mmcblk0p10"
```

Then ran the following: (the img files were in the current directory)

```
adb reboot fastboot
fastboot flash recovery utopic-preinstalled-recovery-armel+grouper.img
fastboot flash boot utopic-preinstalled-boot-armhf+grouper.img
```

Then followed with

```
adb reboot recovery
```

after which the final install with (remember the bzr stuff at the beginning ?)

```
./rootstock-touch-install utopic-preinstalled-touch-armhf.tar.gz utopic-preinstalled-system-armel+grouper.img
```

Good luck - remember the last entry takes a very long time,
 do not (as I did, so many times) give up and reboot.
Take a long lunch or something.

Answer (score 1):

How to start ubuntu-touch on Nexus 7 3G Tilapia (nakasig)?

1. ```
   sudo add-apt-repository ppa:phablet-team/tools
   ```
2. ```
   sudo apt-get update
   ```
3. ```
   sudo apt-get install phablet-tools android-tools-adb android-tools-fastboot
   ```
4. Do all by official manual
5. ```
   phablet-flash ubuntu-system --no-backup -d grouper
   ```
6. ```
   abootimg -x saucy-preinstalled-system-armel+grouper.img
   ```
7. edit `bootimg.cfg`:

   `cmdline = console=tty1 datapart=/dev/mmcblk0p10`
8. ```
   abootimg --create saucy-preinstalled-system-armel+grouper.img -f bootimg.cfg -k zImage -r initrd.img
   ```
9. reboot to bootloader
10. ```
    fastboot flash boot saucy-preinstalled-boot-armhf+grouper.img
    ```
11. reboot device.
12. wait ~60 sec. Enjoy.

Answer (score 0):

Point 6 needs to use `saucy-preinstalled-boot-armhf+grouper.img`

Point 6,7 and 8: instead of extracting the image, `abootimg` offers commands to just update it:

```
abootimg -u saucy-preinstalled-boot-armhf+grouper.img -c "cmdline=console=tty1 datapart=/dev/mmcblk0p10"
```

(you can check with `abootimg -i saucy-preinstalled-boot-armhf+grouper.img` if it worked)